# Redirected to non-HTTPS facebook home page while visiting torrent site

Tags: facebook, url-redirection

I was visiting a sketchy but useful torrent site forum i've used before to find a patch (i know, bad idea) for an old game. Popups are frequent while browsing the forum, but NoScript and Ublock Origin usually block them and close them right away. This one however, redirected successfully to my facebook home page, already logged in, but without HTTPS. I closed it right away, and changed my password using the same browser. here's the redirect order (Do not click unless you know what you are doing):

```
http://quicktask.xyz/?auction_id=18dc01a2c186988&zoneid=858740&pbk2=35202933d2dd7ed48464d1558dfa28ad6377888537279744678&r=%2Foc%2Fhan%2Ftomb&uuid=fc8e1b3b-6c9e-4d04-af11-d833a49b6736&fs=1

http://wadogo.go2cloud.org/aff_r?offer_id=1552&aff_id=4153&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fcampaign%2Flanding.php%3Fcampaign_id%3D736960129747539%26partner_id%3Dinmobi%26placement%3D1f9ba3b35db247cdbaddd10ddf0286ca%26extra_1%3Dwadogo_facebook_726_1021850cf0707867ba938988fc320d%26creative%3D57f46e627d3b4da599aaea9382f36f06%26extra_2%3D4153&urlauth=415746420673275776969747118601

http://www.facebook.com/campaign/landing.php?campaign_id=736960129747539&partner_id=inmobi&placement=1f9ba3b35db247cdbaddd10ddf0286ca&extra_1=wadogo_facebook_726_1021850cf0707867ba938988fc320d&creative=57f46e627d3b4da599aaea9382f36f06&extra_2=4153
```

Would this redirect to my FB page already logged in gain access to my account, and should I take any further action beyond changing my password?

Comment: (3rd link in redirect chain, do not click)

http://www.facebook . com/campaign/landing.php?campaign_id=736960129747539&partner_id=inmobi&placement=1f9ba3b35db247cdbaddd10ddf0286ca&extra_1=wadogo_facebook_726_1021850cf0707867ba938988fc320d&creative=57f46e627d3b4da599aaea9382f36f06&extra_2=4153

Answer (score 1):

Any website can redirect to any other website, and that's not a vulnerability. The place you would have to worry is if merely visiting a particular url takes an action on your account - in essence, this is what a [csrf attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) is. Given Facebook's popularity and large technology budget, it is fairly unlikely you will be victim of a csrf attack on their site. However, if you are, it's unlikely to have revealed your password - it's more likely to have added a friend, followed a page, clicked on an ad, etc. You can [peruse your activity log](https://m.facebook.com/help/activitylog) to review this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised the plain HTTP link actually redirected you there? Unless you were using [an old browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stricttransportsecurity), HSTS should have upgraded your connection from plain HTTP to HTTPS.

This is only really a risk if there are any untrusted networks between you and `facebook.com` and the plain HTTP connection was actually made, and not upgraded by HSTS in your browser.

If you trust your local network, your ISP and you government, then your session will not have been compromised.

If you changed your password and invalidated all other sessions then your exposure will be limited.